# How do i retrieve Windows user preference value for Hyperlink colour?

Tags: delphi, winapi

set in Appearance, overriden by theme(?)
also i suspect this pref is newly introduced (6.0+?)

Comment: what do you want to do with this information? Knowing that would help us answer better.

Comment: I searched google for my problem, and found this question. So I think this is a real question and I had the same question. I know that in Windows Themes hyperlink text color could be adjusted. And the question was how to get this color. And accepted answer is correct, but in Delphi there is special constant, that corresponds to COLOR_HOTLIGHT, is defined in `Graphics` unit: `clHotLight = TColors.SysHotLight;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you mean, but I think you are referring to the GetSysColor setting for [COLOR_HOTLIGHT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is described as:

> Color for a hyperlink or a hot-tracked item.

But as you observe, themed painting doesn't use these settings. The best way to match themed painting is to simply draw with the theme API and the appropriate color will be used.

Comment: Thanks, retrieves proper value. I was under impression what XP and down has no item explicitly marked as 'hyperlink' (talking about Appearance dialog)

Comment: You can use 'clHotLight' constant that corresponds to `COLOR_HOTLIGHT`